# Using Java 7 API to read a file byte by byte

Tags: java, file, input, io, java-7

I have a 2 gb file I want to read in Java (actually four 2gb files). And so there's a new feature in Java 7 that can let me read all the bytes at once.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class reconstructor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Path p = Paths.get("test.txt");     
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            byte[] b = Files.readAllBytes(p);
            Files.write(p, b, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        }

    }

}
```

This is a dumb program that wil read a file with a single byte pre entered in it and continuously read that file and append what it read back onto the same file. Now obviously, the RAM is not big enough to read a 2gb file at one time, let alone four of them, so I was wondering if there was any quick way, without using external libraries (unless that is the only way) to read four files byte by byte so that the RAM does not get overloaded (otherwise I end up with a Java heap error).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading byte by byte is the other extreme solution, and will be very inefficient. You should simply use a BufferedInputStream, and read the bytes chunk by chunk.

Read the [Java IO tutorial about byte streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html).

Comment: Hmm efficiency is not what I am looking for, but this seems to solve my problem regardless in a simple manner. I guess the efficiency is a bonus =) Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try Memory Mapped I/O, the last example in this tutorial: http://www.polarsparc.com/pdf/MemoryMappedIOinJava.pdf

Comment: How does this solve the problem of the RAM not being big enough to hold one of these files let alone four of them?

Comment: @EJP are you familiar with the difference between RAM and virtual memory, and why virtual memory came about? And, are you aware which one is used by memory-mapped file operations in Java? Let's not make SO the Republic of Uninformed.

Comment: New generation do not know sh