# How to one-way synchronize files in two directory structures in java?

Tags: java, file, reference, directory, synchronize

I have two folders, source and target, with files and possible subfolders(directory structure is assumed to be the same, subfolders and files can go into any depth) in them. We want to synchronize the target so that for all files:

> ```
> Exists in source, but not in target -> new, copy over to target
> Exists in target, but not in source -> deleted, delete from the target
> Exists in both, but binary unequal -> changed, copy over from source
> Exists in both, and is binary equal -> unchanged, leave be
> ```

One problem I have with this is checking for existence of a file(the return value of listFiles() doesn't seem to have contains() defined), but a far bigger obstacle is referencing the other directory structure. For example, how would I check if target folder contains file "foo.txt" while iterating through the source folder and finding it there? Here's what I have so far:

```
    public void synchronize(File source, File target) {
    //first loop; accounts for every case except deleted
    if (source.isDirectory()) {
        for (File i : source.listFiles()) {
            if (i.isDirectory()) {
                synchronize(i, /**i's equivalent subdirectory in target*/);
            }
            else if (/**i is new*/) {
                /**Copy i over to the appropriate target folder*/
            }
            else if (/**i is different*/) {
                /**copy i over from source to target*/
            }
            else {/**i is identical in both*/
                /**leave i in target alone*/
            }
        }
        for (File i : target.listFiles()) {
            if (/**i exists in the target but not in source*/) {
                /**delete in target*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT(important):** I thank you guys for all the answers, but the main problem remains unsolved: referring to the other directory, i.e. the stuff in the comments. h22's answer seem to be somewhere in the ballpark, but it's not sufficient, as explained in the comment below it. I'd be very grateful if someone could explain this in even smaller words. From experience, this is exactly the kind of problem that someone more java-savvy could solve in five minutes, whereas I would spend two frustrating weeks rediscovering America.

Comment: if you are doing this on windows, then you may prefer to just call the windows `xcopy` command, which is able to do the hard work for you.

Comment: @bvdb rsync works fine in windows (https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync) and linux, can sync through network, and can minimize bandwidth via xdelta. However, OP seems to want to use java.

Comment: Yes, but I wonder how hard it needs to be java :) I mean maybe he doesn't know there's such a thing like `Runtime.exec("xcopy/rsync ...");`.

Comment: Thanks for the practical tips, guys, but as @tucuxi said, I want to write this in java. It's a school assignment that I need to finish. It's also something to show off at job interviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only visit the source folder recursively. Strip the folder root and address the target location directly:

```
String subPath = sourceFile.getAbsolutePath().substring(sourceRoot.length);
File targetFile = new File(targetRoot + File.separator + subPath);

if (targetFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
  targetFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}
// copy, etc
```

Otherwise you may have difficulties if the target location is missing the required hierarchical folder structure that may go many directories in depth.

Comment: I think I get where you're heading(cut off whatever is is front of the source root, then append the resulting sub-path to whatever is if front of the target root), but my understanding of what exactly this does and where to use it is shaky at best. And what is that .length supposed to do? It gives a "cannot resolve" when left like this and "cannot be applied()" when I add brackets after it.

Answer (score 2):

As wero points out, you can use `aFile.exists()` to see if a given path exists. You should also combine it with `aFile.isFile()` to check whether the path is a normal file (and not, say, a folder).

Checking content-equals is more tricky. I propose the following:

```
 boolean sameContents(File fa, File fb) throws IOException {
      Path a = a.toPath();
      Path b = b.toPath();
      if (Files.size(a) != Files.size(b)) return false;
      return Arrays.equals(
           Files.readAllBytes(a), Files.readAllBytes(b));
 }
```

But only if the files are expected to be small; otherwise you could run out of memory trying to compare them in one go (required to use `Arrays.equals`). If you have large files in there, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27379155/15472) proposes Apache Commons IO's `FileUtils.contentEquals()`.

Note that both the above code and `contentEquals` only compare files, and not folders. To compare folders, you will need to use recursion, calling `sameContents` or equivalent on each same-named, same-sized file, and erroring out if no match is found for a particular pathname either in source or in destination.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a target directory `File targetDir` and a source file `File sourceFile` in a source directory you can check the existence of the corresponding target file by writing:

```
 File targetFile = new File(targetDir, sourceFile.getName());
 boolean exists  = targetFile.exists();
```