# JFileChooser to select multiple text files and compare them

Tags: java, compare, jfilechooser

I want to select multiple text files using a JFileChooser and then compare them. 
The code to choose multiple files is as below

```
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    Component frame = null;
    chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
    File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
```

How do i use the file handle to compare multiple files. Is it possible to compare multiple text files using this method.
I have multiple text files, and i want to check if the contents of all the files match. If the contents are exactly the same, i see MATCH and if the text files are different, i see FAIL along with the difference in content.
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: What do you want to compare? The text or the words? Please add some more detail to your question...

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"?  Display a list of differences on the console (aka `diff`)? Display a side-by-side comparison (aka `WinMerge` on Windows or similar tools on Linux)?  There's nothing built-in to Java to do either of those tasks.

Comment: a brief description on what i want to compare is added. Basically I have multiple text files, and i want to check if the contents of all the files match. If the contents are exactly the same, i see MATCH and if the text files are different, i see FAIL along with the difference in content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#contentEquals(java.io.File,%20java.io.File))

**example:**

```
for(int i=0; i<files.length-1; i++) 
    for(int j=i+1; j<files.length; j++)
        if(FileUtils.contentEquals(files[i], files[j]))
            System.out.println("file #" + i + " and file #" + j + " are identical.";
        else
            System.out.println("file #" + i + " and file #" + j + " are different.";
```

---

**example#2** - without using external libraries
you can use the technique described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27379430/2815219) answer.

```
for(int i=0; i<files.length-1; i++) {
    for(int j=i+1; j<files.length; j++) {
        byte[] f1 = Files.readAllBytes(files[i]);
        byte[] f2 = Files.readAllBytes(files[j]);

        if (Arrays.equals(f1, f2))
            System.out.println("file #" + i + " and file #" + j + " are identical.";
        else
            System.out.println("file #" + i + " and file #" + j + " are different.";
    }
}
```

*P.S.: Since you didn't mentioned it in your question, I assumed here that you want to compare the contents of two files and determine if they are equal or not.*

Comment: Yes Raman , that is what i want to do. Thanks for the help. Just a query, does it require a specific java version to work. FileUtil cannot be resolved is the error which i face

Comment: Hi @sam did you import FileUtils? like this `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;`

Comment: I will have to download **org.apache.commons.io.jar** for that separately i guess because eclipse does not give suggestion for any such import as of now. i have to make a jar file and distribute the same among other members and i am not sure all of them will have that . is there some other way, other than FileUtils.

Comment: @sam if you don't wanna use external libraries, then please refer to example #2 of my updated answer.

Comment: @sam You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)