# What is the fastest method to compare two large files in Java

Tags: java, checksum, file-comparison

Currently we have a nightly automation run that does a comparison between a resulting test file produced by our software and a baseline file.  This comparison is is done several times and the files are large.  The file comparison is the bottle neck in our test automation.

File comparison is currently done via buffering line by line comparison.

I was thinking of doing a checksum comparison of the two files (then doing the line by line check if the checksums do not match).  Is this the best approach?  Is there a public library someone one would like to suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Do the files have to be identical, or different? Do you have to see the differences?

Comment: and please define "large". Comparing checksums is the best way if they already are pre-computed, if you have to compute them first it certainly is on of the least performant ways.

Comment: You can start by checking file size, if they dont match they are already different, also the checksum of the whole file is a good way to check equalness

Comment: Line-by-line probably means converting the file bytes to characters according to some character encoding, finding newlines, creating Strings representing the lines that have to be garbage-collected when the line is no longer needed etc., so switching to lower-level, byte-buffer I/O might improve speed - but first use a profiler to find out if that's the bottleneck...

Comment: The files are supposed to be the same, we're looking to see and flag those that are different.  We assert that they are the same.

Comment: File size are around 192 K, which in retrospect isn't too large, but their comparison is the bottle neck in our test automation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if two files store the same content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379059/determine-if-two-files-store-the-same-content)

Comment: IMHO for files that have to be equal (byte by byte) and sizes up to a few hundred kilobytes I would first compare their sizes and if these are equal just allocate two byte arrays of the right size, read in the files completly and just compare the byte arrays. For larger files I would allocate two block buffers of may 128KB and read the files blockwise until either the blocks differ or the files are completly read in.

Answer (score 2):

Is 10 ms good enough to compare two 260K files? (on Windows laptop)

If so you can use `java.security.DigestInputStream` to calculate and compare Hash.

Of course doing, check files length before.
If issue is about many files you need to compare, consider using parallel threads to compare each pair.

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        File file1 = new File("D:\\tmp\\tests\\logs\\test.log");
        File file2 = new File("D:\\tmp\\tests\\logs\\test-cp.log");

        if (!file1.exists() || !file2.exists()) {
            System.out.println("One of the file not found.");
            return;
        }
        if (file1.length() != file2.length()) {
            System.out
                    .println("Files are not identical - not equal length.");
            return;
        }

        long f1Length = file1.length();
        long f2Length = file2.length();

        System.out.println("Check Digest method:");
        FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
        DigestInputStream dgStream1 = new DigestInputStream(fis1,
                MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"));
        FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
        DigestInputStream dgStream2 = new DigestInputStream(fis2,
                MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"));
        // most expensive is dgStream1.getMessageDigest() so do it only at last read
        dgStream1.on(false);
        dgStream2.on(false);

        long f1ReadTotal = 0;
        long f2ReadTotal = 0;

        long start = System.nanoTime();

        int read = 0;
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024 * 128];
        do {
            if ((f1Length - f1ReadTotal) < (1024 * 128)) {
                // last read 
                dgStream1.on(true);
            }
            read = dgStream1.read(buff);
            f1ReadTotal += read > 0 ? read : 0;
        } while (read > 0);

        read = 0;
        do {
            if ((f2Length - f2ReadTotal) < (1024 * 128)) {
                // last read
                dgStream2.on(true);
            }
            read = dgStream2.read(buff);
            f2ReadTotal += read > 0 ? read : 0;
        } while (read > 0);

        long runTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
        if (Arrays.equals(dgStream1.getMessageDigest().digest(), dgStream2
                .getMessageDigest().digest())) {
            System.out.println("Files are identical. completed in "
                    + (runTime / 1000000) + " ms. [" + runTime + " ns.]");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Files are not identical. completed in "
                    + (runTime / 1000000) + " ms. [" + runTime + " ns.]");
        }

        fis1.close();
        fis2.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Main point there that `getMessageDigest()` is most time expensive operation, so do it once at last read.

BTW: code is just an idea. Real code must be more careful especially about "last read" and definitely can be more optimal.