# How to read two big text files in one Hash Map

Tags: java, file, data-structures, lambda, time-complexity

I have two text file like

```
     file1. txt                file2.txt

  http://example.com       http://example.com
  http://example.com       http://example.com
```

I want to read these two files line by line and compare output of both.
like line1 output of file1 with line1 output of file2

So how can we read these two files in efficient way if they have millions of lines.

Can we use java lambda expression?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if two files store the same content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379059/determine-if-two-files-store-the-same-content)

Comment: I don't want to check duplicate i want to pass line1 of file 1 and line1 of file2 in one method and after some process want to return result.

Comment: Try something like: 

`File f1 = new File("file1.txt");
File f2 = new File("file2.txt");
boolean areEqual = FileUtils.contentEquals(f1, f2);`

Comment: "I don't want to check duplicate" - Then tell us what you want to do, exactly.

Comment: See i have url in both the files and i want to compare response of url 1 of file 1 and url 1 of file 2

Comment: "i want to compare response " - Response of... what?  A `GET` request?  A `POST` request?

Comment: Get request....

Comment: Do you know how long it would take to send `GET` requests to millions of websites?

Comment: No, Actually i have millions of url and and every url will return response in Json so i want to compare response of url1 of file1  is equal to url1 of file2 or not

Comment: Thanks for your time but i got solution by Gagan singh. He gave solution without asking any questions and without giving -2 to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static <R> List<R> compare(Path path1, Path path2, BiFunction<String, String, R> compare) throws IOException
{
    List<R> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Stream<String> s1 = Files.lines(path1);
         Stream<String> s2 = Files.lines(path2))
    {
        Iterator<String> itr1 = s1.iterator();
        Iterator<String> itr2 = s2.iterator();
        //compare only till both the files have some entry
        while (itr1.hasNext() && itr2.hasNext())
        {
            list.add(compare.apply(itr1.next(), itr2.next()));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for solution like this

Comment: For those curious, `Files#lines` lazily populates the `Stream`, so the entire file won't be loaded. Very efficient usage of this method.

Answer (score 2):

There is no particularly efficient way.  The best you will be able to do it:

```
// pseudo-code
file1 = open(...)
file2 = open(...)
while (file1 not at EOF) {
    url1 = file1.readLine()
    url2 = file2.readLine()
    if (url1 != url2) {
        connection1 = open(url1)
        connection2 = open(url2)
        // deal with "error" responses
        if (connnection1.contentLength != connection2.contentLength) {
            // not same
        } else {
            // compare bytes for connection output streams)
        }
    } else {
        // same
    }
}
```

There are a couple of "tweaks" in the above code:

1. If the URLs are identical they don't need to be compared
2. If or other URL doesn't "open" then you shouldn't compare them
3. If the content lengths are different you can skip comparing them
4. If documents are not equal, you probably only need to read part of them.

You may also be able to get a speedup by doing a few comparisons in parallel.  The risk is that you will overwhelm your network or the remote servers, or be rate limited or blocked by the remote servers.

---

> So how can we read these two files in efficient way if they have millions of lines.

Millions of URLs to compare is going to take a long time if you actually need to compare the documents.  The limiting factor will be either the network (bandwidth, latency, congestion, etc) or the performance of the remote servers.

> Can we use java lambda expression?

It won't make a noticeable difference to the performance.

Comment: What is content length?

Comment: @shubhambansal if the content received from the `GET` requests have different `Content-Length` parameters, it is not necessary to check for message equality - they have different lengths and can't be equal.

Comment: @shubhambansal - It is documented in the HTTP specification ... and in the javadocs for the Http client API that you will be using.

Comment: To add onto that, if it is possible that two requests have different `Content-Length`s, but semantically are equal, then this check must not be performed.

Comment: @Obicere - I think what you are trying to say is that if the content-lengths are the same, you cannot assume that the documents are equal.

Comment: Okay i understood. Thanks +1

Comment: @StephenC quite the opposite. If the content-lengths are different, you cannot assume the documents are inequal. If there is extra whitespace in a JSON request, the two JSON structures will be identical but have different `Content-Length` values.

Comment: It depends on the precise criteria for deciding that two documents are the same.  I have assumed byte-for-byte identical, but that could be too strict for some use-cases.  But, if you start to go down the "semantically equal" rabbit hole, the problem gets a whole lot more complicated ... and expensive / slow.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking sounds pretty simple. The general idea is:

```
open file1
open file2
while not (end of file1 or end of file2)
    read response from file1
    read response from file2
    compare response1 and response2
end while
close file1
close file2
```

That way you only have to keep two responses in memory at any time. It doesn't matter how many responses are in the files.