# Is there any way to get the hashcode of an InputStream using Guava?

Tags: java, file, hash, inputstream, guava

Is there a way to get the HashCode of an InputStream in Java,
I am trying to upload a picture using the `<p:fileUpload/>` from PrimeFaces, converting it into a HashCode and comparing it to another picture.

At the moment I'm trying this:

```
public void save(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
        HashCode hashCode = null;
        HashCode hashCodeCompare = null;
        hashCode = Files.asByteSource(new File(event.toString())).hash(Hashing.murmur3_128(50));
        hashCodeCompare = Files.asByteSource(new File(FilePathOfFileToCompare)).hash(Hashing.murmur3_128(50));
        boolean hashTrueFalse;
        if(hashCode.equals(hashCodeCompare)) {
            System.out.println("true");
        } else{
            System.out.println("false");
        }

        try (InputStream input = event.getFile().getInputstream()) {
            String imageName = generateFileName() + "." + fileExtensions(event.getFile().getFileName());
            String imageLink = PICTURE_DESTINATION + "\\" + imageName;


            Picture picture = new Picture();
            picture.setPictureUrl(imageLink);
            pictureService.createOrUpdate(picture);

            personForm.getCurrentPersonDTO().setPictureDTO(pictureMapper.toDTO(picture));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to turn the `InputStream` into a hashcode?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to get the HashCode of a stream or of an image? You can get a HashCode of any Java object by calling `.hashCode()` of course, but more importantly is what the int represents and why you want to use it.

Comment: I try to Upload a picture, and turn it into a hashvalue, and compare it with another picture to see if it already exists.
I tried using ```.hashCode()``` but it gave me a different hashCode if I tried comparing the same imiges as an inputstream and as a file

Comment: And if you're trying to use HashCode to comparing images, what if the image is a JPG or other image that is stored using lossy compression? The image file bits could be quite different, but the images themselves could be functionally the same.

Comment: So what would be your prefered methode of choice to compare an picture upload and an actual picture?

I just need some iedeas/input from outside because im workng on this problem for 2,5h now D:

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. If you're trying to check if the bits of two reasonable sized files are the same, then you could read all bytes as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27379430/522444). If the images are large, then you could compare hashes of their streams similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27379566/522444). If it's the actual image appearance that you need to compare, then that's a whole different thing altogether.

Comment: I want to compare if the Image I uploaded already exists! Thats all I want to do. To eveluate if I need to save a new picture or just use an existing!

Comment: Read the InputStream into a byte[] then run a hash function on the byte array. You probably don't want to use hashCode() for this. Use SHA256 instead.

Comment: This is not an XY problem. Comparing image hashes is a perfectly reasonable and widely used approach to this exact match deduplication problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to read the InputStream if you are going to calculate a hash on the bytes it contains. First read the InputSteam to a byte[].

With Guava use ByteStreams:

```
InputStream in = ...;
byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(in);
```

An alternative popular way to do this is to use [Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/):

```
InputStream in = ...;
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
```

Then you can call Arrays.hashCode() on the byte array:

```
int hash = java.util.Arrays.hashCode(bytes);
```

However you might consider using SHA256 as your hash function instead as you are less likely to have a collision:

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] sha256Hash = digest.digest(bytes);
```

If you don't want to read the entire stream to an in memory byte array you can calculate the hash as the InputStream is being read by someone else. For example you might want to stream the InputStream to disk to into a db. Guava provides a class that wraps an InputStream that does this for you [HashingInputStream](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/HashingInputStream.html):

First wrap your InputStream with a HashinInputStream

```
HashingInputStream hin = new HashingInputStream(Hashing.sha256(), in);
```

Then let that HashingInputStream be read in any way you like

```
while(hin.read() != -1);
```

Then get the hash from the HashingInputStream

```
byte[] sha256Hash = hin.hash().asBytes();
```

Answer (score 13):

What you want to do is `ByteStreams.copy(input, Funnels.asOutputStream(hasher))` where `hasher` is acquired from e.g. `Hashing.sha256().newHasher()`.  Then, call `hasher.hash()` to get the resulting `HashCode`.

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't have more upvotes, most of the other solutions require a copy of the input stream to a byte[], or looping through the input stream outside the hasher.

Comment: ByteStreams.copy(in, out) is looping over the input stream for you. The downside to using this solution is that you are using the hasher as a sink. As such you lose the bytes when you hash them. That is often not desirable, say for example you are processing an input stream that a user has just uploaded. You both want to pass the bytes onto storage and generate the hash. But here the bytes will be lost as they are read from the InputStream.

Comment: @bhspencer: Honestly, in most cases in practice I don't actually want to keep the bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use   `Files.asByteSource(fileSource.getFile()).hash(hashFunction).padToLong()`