# How to check for a blank pdf in mule?

Tags: java, pdf, mule, mule-esb

I have a situation where I have to check if the pdf received from the webservice is blank pdf and return appropriate error response in the mule api if the pdf is blank.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with blank? size == 0kb?

Comment: There is no content in the pdf when I open it using pdf reader. But it has some size.

Comment: You have to look the content of your "blank pdf", because it only seems to be blank, but has content in it. Now you could check, whether the content of the file is always the same and check futre pdf-files, if they have same content. 
But when your "blank files" have always different content There'll be trouble

Comment: I think there will be the same blank pdf. Assuming it is always the same blank pdf, Someone can answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is always the same:

```
byte[] sampleBytes = Files.readAllBytes(sample);
byte[] incomingBytes = Files.readAllBytes(incomingPdf);

if (f1.equals(f2) {
    // do something..
}
```

How you get the `byte []` is your business, just check them for equality.

[Check two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379059/determine-if-two-files-store-the-same-content)