# Poor performance reading images on java

Tags: java, macos

I've written a small application for personal use in macOs using java (the only language I know) that reads a directory and compare the images found in it with every other image.

Edit: As user dbush pointed out, here is the code I should've posted:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
            file1 = files.get(i).getAbsolutePath();

            for (int j = i + 1; j < files.size(); j++) {
                file2 = files.get(j).getAbsolutePath();
                System.out.println("Comparing " + files.get(i).getName() + sp + files.get(j).getName());
                System.out.println(Arrays.equals(extractBytes(file1), extractBytes(file2)));
            }
        }

private static byte[] extractBytes(String imageName) throws IOException {
        // open image
        File imgPath = new File(imageName);
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = getSample(imgPath);

        // get DataBufferBytes from Raster
        WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
        DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

        return (data.getData());
    }

    private static BufferedImage getSample(File f) {

        BufferedImage img = null;

        Rectangle sourceRegion = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10); // The region you want to extract

        try {
            ImageInputStream stream1 = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(f); // File or input stream

            Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream1);

            if (readers.hasNext()) {
                ImageReader reader = readers.next();
                reader.setInput(stream1);

                ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
                param.setSourceRegion(sourceRegion); // Set region

                img = reader.read(0, param); // Will read only the region specified

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return img;

    }
```

It involves reading two images in a byte array and comparing both. The problem is that it takes a long time to do this, even if I sample a small portion of each image.

Should I re-write the same application in C or swift for better performance, considering I'll be running it on macOs from the terminal? Or it will do minimal difference.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You're probably doing something inefficient in your java code.  You should post a question with that.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about why you are doing this?  Is it to see if the files are exactly the same or is is just parts of the image?  How big are the files?

Comment: It looks like you're currently only comparing a subsection of the images.  Is this deliberate(checking for a watermark/common section) or just for performance?  If it's the later and you're just trying to check if two files are bytewise identical, the correct/efficient way is a checksum.

Comment: I got tons of pictures taken throughout the years in my computer, spread all over the place. Some may have been renamed, some copied to another directories. So, I would like to check them without opening them to find the repeated ones.

Comment: I'm checking a small section just for the sake of performance, and it did work pretty good so far for my needs

Comment: If it's just the same file different place/with different names then the answer is just take an md5sum and compare those.  Alternative answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379059/determine-if-two-files-store-the-same-content

Comment: Your double nested for loops at the top have O(n^2) complexity.In other words if you have 10,000 photos, you need to extract bytes 2*100,000,000 times. This would take a very long time. By far the simplest solution is to calculate some kind of hash of all the photos in question(md5sum would be good for this). Then store the hashes in a `HashSet`, which would allow you to quickly find duplicates.

Comment: I'm really impressed by the answers. I think I'll start over and go for the md5sum approach with a HashSet. Thank you guys for your help!