# Compare contents of pdf in Java

Tags: java, pdf, testing, junit

I am writing Java unit tests and want to compare the contents of a generated pdf to one saved as a resource. I thought I'd be able to read the contents of both into byte arrays and compare, but I'm not able to get the byte arrays to match.

I've tried comparing two pdfs where one is a copy of the other and still no dice, even if I set the createTime, lastModifiedTime, and lastAccessTime of both pdfs.

After using [diff checker](https://www.diffchecker.com/image-diff/), I think the problem is how I'm setting the metadata in code. On my laptop, the createTime, modifiedTime, etc are the same in both files I'm trying to compare, but in the diff checker the only difference is the update time and create time, which have not been updated from their initial values.

Does anyone know how to compare the contents of a binary file without considering metadata?

Here is my code, for reference

```
File actualFile = new File("/tmp/" + pdfName);
Files.setLastModifiedTime(actualFile.toPath(), FileTime.fromMillis(testDateInMillis));
Files.setAttribute(actualFile.toPath(), "creationTime", FileTime.fromMillis(testDateInMillis));
Files.setAttribute(actualFile.toPath(), "lastAccessTime", FileTime.fromMillis(testDateInMillis));
File expectedFile = new File("src/test/resources/test-pdfs/" + pdfName);
Files.setAttribute(expectedFile.toPath(), "creationTime", FileTime.fromMillis(testDateInMillis));
Files.setAttribute(expectedFile.toPath(), "lastAccessTime", FileTime.fromMillis(testDateInMillis));
Files.setLastModifiedTime(expectedFile.toPath(), FileTime.fromMillis(testDateInMillis));

byte[] filebytes = Files.readAllBytes(expectedFile.toPath());
byte[] filebytes2 = Files.readAllBytes(actualFile.toPath());
Assertions.assertEquals(filebytes, filebytes2);
```

Comment: This question has a lot of good answers [Determine if two files store the same content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379059/determine-if-two-files-store-the-same-content), you could take a look into the FileUtils library and see how they do it, or for small files you could read them to byte arrays, or for large files you could get a hash of each file and compare them. This may be the best option for Java12 and above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56680991/1270000

Comment: I've tried all of that with no success. The pdfs render exactly the same but it could also be that there's some difference in the binary representation that I don't know how to interpret that's different. Although I'm not sure what that could be because I generated both exactly the same way, so still thinking it's metadata related

Comment: Without seeing how you generate the PDF I can't comment, but that being the case, I strongly recommend using a PDF library that is able to process the contents of a PDF file. Once you have them loaded as objects within your code then you can compare the relevant aspects (page count, page contents etc) and ignore the bits that dont matter (metadata, ownership, tags, digital signatures, etc). If you only care about them rendering the same, then you could make and compare snapshots of each page, or you could use an existing library: https://github.com/red6/pdfcompare

Comment: Holy smokes I don't know how didn't come across that library in all of my googling. This is perfect, thank you!

Comment: Which library provides this `Assertions` class? A lot of unit test tools have (or had) a separate `assertArrayEquals`.